# ES6 exports/imports use-case, compared to traditional namespacing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I don't understand WHY and in what scenario this would be used..

My current web setup consists of lots of components, which are just functions or factory functions, each in their own file, and each function "rides" the app namespace, like : `app.component.breadcrumbs = function(){...` and so on.

Then GULP just combines all the files, and I end up with a single file, so a page controller (each "page" has a controller which loads the components the page needs) can just load it's components, like: `app.component.breadcrumbs(data)`.

All the components can be easily accessed on demand, and the single javascript file is well cached and everything. This way of work seems extremely good, never saw any problem with this way of work. of course, this can (and is) be scaled nicely.

**So how are ES6 imports for functions any better than what I described?**

what's the deal with importing functions instead of just attaching them to the App's namespace? it makes much more sense for them to be "attached".

#### Files structure

```
/dist/app.js                     // web app namespace and so on
/dist/components/breadcrumbs.js  // some component
/dist/components/header.js       // some component
/dist/components/sidemenu.js     // some component
/dist/pages/homepage.js          // home page controller

// GULP concat all above to
/js/app.js // this file is what is downloaded
```

#### Then inside `homepage.js` it can look like this:

```
app.routes.homepage = function(){
    "use strict";
    var DOM = { page : $('#page') };

    // append whatever components I want to this page
    DOM.page.append(
        app.component.header(),
        app.component.sidemenu(),
        app.component.breadcrumbs({a:1, b:2, c:3})
    )
};
```

*This is an extremely simplified code example but you get the point*

Comment: A **very** good project & wiki explaining things - https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/ES6-modules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers to this are probably a little subjective, but I'm going to do my best.

At the end of the day, both methods allow support creating a namespace for a piece of functionality so that it does not conflict with other things. Both work, but in my view, modules, ES6 or any other, provide a few extra benefits.

#### Explicit dependencies

Your example seems very bias toward a "load everything" approach, but you'll generally find that to be uncommon. If your `components/header.js` needs to use `components/breadcrumbs.js`, assumptions must be made. Has that file been bundled into the overall JS file? You have no way of knowing. You're two options are

1. Load everything
2. Maintain a file somewhere that explicitly lists what needs to be loaded.

The first option is easy and in the short term is probably fine. The second is complicated for maintainability because it would be maintained as an external list, it would be very easy to stop needing one of your component file but forget to remove it.

It also means that you are essentially defining your own syntax for dependencies when again, one has now been defined in the language/community.

What happens when you want to start splitting your application into pieces? Say you have an application that is a single large file that drives 5 pages on your site, because they started out simple and it wasn't big enough to matter. Now the application has grown and should be served with a separate JS file per-page. You have now lost the ability to use option #1, and some poor soul would need to build this new list of dependencies for each end file.

What if you start using a file in a new places? How do you know which JS target files actually need it? What if you have twenty target files?

What if you have a library of components that are used across your whole company, and one of they starts relying on something new? How would that information be propagated to any number of the developers using these?

Modules allow you to know with 100% certainty what is used where, with automated tooling. You only need to package the files you actually use.

#### Ordering

Related to dependency listing is dependency ordering. If your library needs to create a special subclass of your `header.js` component, you are no longer only accessing `app.component.header()` from `app.routes.homepage()`, which would presumable be running at DOMContentLoaded. Instead you need to access it during the initial application execution. Simple concatenation offers no guarantees that it will have run yet. If you are concatenating alphabetically and your new things is `app.component.blueHeader()` then it would fail.

This applies to anything that you might want to do immediately at execution time. If you have a module that immediately looks at the page when it runs, or sends an AJAX request or anything, what if it depends on some library to do that?

This is another argument agains #1 (Load everything) so you start having to maintain a list again. That list is again going to be a custom things you'll have come up with instead of a standardized system.

How do you train new employees to use all of this custom stuff you've built?

Modules execute files in order based on their dependencies, so you know for sure that the stuff you depend on will have executed and will be available.

#### Scoping

Your solution treats everything as a standard script file. That's fine, but it means that you need to be extremely careful to not accidentally create global variables by placing them in the top-level scope of a file. This can be solved by manually adding `(function(){   ...  })();` around file content, but again, it's one more things you need to know to do instead of having it provided for you by the language.

#### Conflicts

`app.component.*` is something you've chosen, but there is nothing special about it, and it is global. What if you wanted to pull in a new library from Github for instance, and it also used that same name? Do you refactor your whole application to avoid conflicts?

What if you need to load two versions of a library? That has obvious downsides if it's big, but there are plenty of cases where you'll still want to trade big for non-functional. If you rely on a global object, it is now up to that library to make sure it also exposes an API like jQuery's `noConflict`. What if it doesn't? Do you have to add it yourself?

#### Encouraging smaller modules

This one may be more debatable, but I've certainly observed it within my own codebase. With modules, and the lack of boilerplate necessary to write modular code with them, developers are encouraged to look closely on how things get grouped. It is very easy to end up making "utils" files that are giant bags of functions thousands of lines long because it is easier to add to an existing file that it is to make a new one.

#### Dependency webs

Having explicit imports and exports makes it very clear what depends on what, which is great, but the side-effect of that is that it is much easier to think critically about dependencies. If you have a giant file with 100 helper functions, that means that if any one of those helpers needs to depend on something from another file, it needs to be loaded, even if nothing is ever using that helper function at the moment. This can easily lead to a large web of unclear dependencies, and being aware of dependencies is a huge step toward thwarting that.

#### Standardization

There is a lot to be said for standardization. The JavaScript community has moved heavily in the direction of reusable modules. This means that if you hope into a new codebase, you don't need to start off by figuring out how things relate to eachother. Your first step, at least in the long run, won't be to wonder whether something is AMD, CommonJS, System.register or what. By having a syntax in the language, it's one less decision to have to make.

The long and short of it is, modules offer a standard way for code to interoperate, whether that be your own code, or third-party code.

Your current process is to concatenate everything always into a single large file, only ever execute things after the whole file has loaded and you have 100% control over all code that you are executing, then you've essentially defined your own module specification based on your own assumptions about your specific codebase. That is totally fine, and no-one is forcing you to change that.

No such assumptions can be made for the general case of JavaScript code however. It is precisely the objective of modules to provide a standard in such a way as to not break existing code, but to also provide the community with a way forward. What modules offer is another approach to that, which is one that is standardized, and one that offers clearer paths for interoperability between your own code and third-party code.

Comment: I am concatenation per folder, so all the files in that folder (and sub-folders) are known to be concatenated into 1 single file. if I want to split something, I just move that file into some other folder which I know generates another file.

Comment: All the concatenated code is ordered in GULP by hierarchy of dependency, so there cannot be a situation where something is needed but isn't available. This can never happen. I've made big websites with this method, with many pages, and even more components, and didn't had any scaling issues. also, there can be no conflicts, since the namespace is using `const app = {}`, so that solves that. for globals, I don't really need to be careful, since it never happens, and even if so, the GULP task for linting which will alert of such a thing, so it isn't a concern.

Comment: `What if you start using a file in a new places? How do you know which JS target files actually need it? What if you have twenty target files?` - sorry, didn't understand that one.. could you explain?

Comment: `Modules allow you to know with 100% certainty what is used where, with automated tooling. You only need to package the files you actually use.` well, that's what i'm struggling to understand. been writing js for 10 years and never had any thought like "what is used in this code?" I mean, there are functions and function calls, that's basically 90% of what javascript is, if I see a function call, then I will assume that function is available somewhere, and in my case, it would be obvious where that is: `app.component.header()`.. all the components are available from anywhere..always

Comment: Concatenating a folder only works if nothing in each file runs until everything has run. What if you have a file in the folder that subclasses one later in the folder? The can be no conflicts in "app" because you have full control over your code. I'm answering in the general sense. If you are using third-party code, you do not have that control. "What if you start using a file in a new places?" doesn't apply to the case of "concat everything", but some of my other points argue against that approach since you may very well have a module that you only want to use part of.

Comment: "Modules allow you to know with 100% certainty" again answering the general case. What if you only want to package part of a module? What if one piece of it is 2megs of code and you only want to use a tiny helper that is in the same folder? Yes, you could write a specific step in your gulp file to do that, it just means you're spreading that knowledge around in both the place where the helper is used, and into your build process, and there isn't really a reason the build process should have to know what files depend on what.

Comment: It seems like the core thing, based on your questions, is that modules offer a standard way for code to interoperate. If you have full 100% control over your entire codebase, use no third-party code and your entire codebase is always, 100% of the time bundled into a single giant file, then you end up mostly getting the scoping point out of it.

Comment: Yeah well, for those specific things which are needed just once for some page I use `requirejs`. Thanks for the good explanation! the point about using a piece of code elsewhere is a very good one, since a component isn't really "bound" to any namespace it could be used easily elsewhere. Thing is, all the files are concatenated anyway (for obvious performance reasons), so should I convert all components to modules and start importing them, or just leave it as it. Seems like modules are good for **very** large application (like Facebook), and not small/medium ones.

Comment: I'd say using them in a new codebase is still a good idea, but if you've got an existing codebase it's entirely a decision of what tech-debt is worth it. The application I work on is 1500 files for instance, but some of them are only used on certain pages. Folder structure is great for organization, but doesn't make to a dependency graph. It also comes down to re-usability. For instance we have a library of common pieces we use across many applications, and if we used a custom system we'd have to duplicate it into each repo. Easier to rely on standardized tooling.

Comment: You know, I'm just amazed by this. if this really is as good as you make it sound, I really don't get it how come in 2015 this isn't even [supported yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) I mean, couldn't they just have learned that from other languages 30 years ago and save all the bother when the web started to really evolve 10 years ago?

Comment: Also, what happens if you import the same function more than one? how can you be sure something wasn't already imported from somewhere else? or does it even matter?

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20 :) You can import the same thing multiple times if you give it a different name. Using the same name twice is an error just like declaring `let x; let x` is an error. `var` is the odd one out there. As for "has this been imported already", it doesn't matter unless you have if the same, and if it's not the same name, I'd say that's more of a stylistic an/or linter question.

Comment: @vsync: `I really don't get it how come in 2015 this isn't even supported yet ` - While the language specification can take a while to evolve and become widely implemented, module systems for JavaScript that achieve similar goals to ES6's `import` have have been around for a while. From what I can tell, they started to surface around 2008/2009.